# How to apply colorAxis.stops with heatmap in Jaspersoft Studio 6.0.1?

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

JasperReports Studio's heat-map chart is based on Highcharts, so I can use the Highcharts API to customize charts through the advanced properties dialog. But I can't figure out how to apply a non-linear color gradient to a heat-map chart.

What I have tried:

I went to `Edit Chart Properties > Advanced Properties` and added the property `colorAxis.stops`, which requires an array of tuples. But no matter what format I try to supply the array, I just end up with a broken chart.

e.g. `java.util.Arrays.asList("{0, #ff0000}", "{0.5, #ffff00}", "{0.9, #00cc00}")` displays a heat-map with no data.

How can I supply the array to this property so that I can get a non-linear gradient? (Red to Yellow to Green)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem. Write this as an expression in the `colorAxis.stops` property:

`java.util.Arrays.asList
(
    java.util.Arrays.asList(0, "#FF0000"),
    java.util.Arrays.asList(0.25, "#FF9900"),
    java.util.Arrays.asList(0.5, "#FFFF00"),
    java.util.Arrays.asList(1, "#00CC00")
)`

Reference: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/advanced-formatting-new-html5-charts